# Statements regarding sequences and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $(a_n), (b_n)$ are sequences then

$1.$ If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n = L>0$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_nb_n = \infty$. **True**

$2.$ If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n = -\infty$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (a_n+b_n) = \infty$. **False since $\infty-\infty$ is undefined.**

$3.$ If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n = -\infty$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_nb_n = -\infty$. **True**

$4.$ If neither $(a_n), (b_n)$ converge then $(a_nb_n)$ doesn't converge. **False since $(\frac{1}{n})$ and $n$ doesn't converge individually but when multplied they converge to 1.**

$5.$ If $(|a_n|)$ converge then $(a_n)$ converge. **False since $(|(-1)^n|)$ converge but  $((-1)^n)$ doesnt converge. However the converse of this statement is true.**

$6.$ If $a_n=0$ for every $n$ then $\sum a_n$  converges. **True. Sum converges to $0$.**

$7.$ If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges to infinity. **True**

$8.$ If $\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum (a_n +  b_n)$ converges. **True**

$9.$ If $a_n>c>0$ for every $n$ then $\sum a_n$ diverges to infinity. **True**

$10.$ If $\sum a_n$ diverges and $(b_n)$ is bounded then $\sum a_nb_n$ diverges to infinity. **True**

$11.$ If $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum (a_n)^2$ converges. **True.**

Are these answers correct?

Comment: _What_ question are you asking?

Comment: Edited the title.

Comment: But you are supposed to ask only one question at a time. Additionally, only six questions can be asked per day.

Comment: So I am supposed to make 11 different posts for just a confirmation of true and false. Besides my only question is whether these answers are correct or not.

Comment: _Yes..._${}{}{}$

Comment: #10 is false. So is #7, if $a_n$ is allowed to be negative. (The key for #7 is "diverges _to infinity_".)

Comment: I some cases you are correct that a proposition is false, but your rationale is not quite right.  Regarding 7) The series diverges but not necessarily to infinity.  8) I don't think that is correct in the case of conditionally convergent series.

Comment: @DougM Re: #8, I'm pretty sure it is correct, though it makes sense to be skeptical.

Comment: I'd review your reason for 5; this is not a valid example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your answers look alright. A few remarks:

> $7.$ If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges to infinity. **True**

Do you know anything about the sign of $a_n$? If not, note that the convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies that $a_n \to 0$, but not that $a_n > 0$; i.e. it's possible that $a_n <0$.

Also note that it doesn't even have to diverge to $\pm\infty$, for example:
$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \implies \frac{1}{a_n} = (-1)^nn$$

> $10.$ If $\sum a_n$ diverges and $(b_n)$ is bounded then $\sum a_nb_n$ diverges to infinity. **True**

If $\sum a_n$ diverges, it doesn't necessarily diverge to infinity (think of $1-1+1-1+1-\ldots$ for example); now take $b_n \equiv 1$.

And as pointed out by Akiva Weinberger in the comment, you can even make it converge (e.g. take $b_n = \tfrac{1}{n}$ and keep $a_n$ as above).

Comment: So for 7 the correction is that divergence can be to positive or negative infinity?

Comment: For #10, you can even make $\sum a_nb_n$ converge.

Comment: for number 7, suppose $a_n = (-\frac 12)^n$  then $\sum \frac 1{a_n} = \sum (-2)^n $ wich clearly diverges but not to infinity or negative infinity.

Comment: #7; indeed, I was adding a different example to my answer.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Indeed, I added this.

Comment: A simpler example: Let $a_n=1$, and $b_n$ be any convergent series.

Answer (score 1):

For 2., "$\infty-\infty$ is undefined" is not an acceptable justification. You need to actually produce two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ with the stated properties and then show that $\lim(a_n+b_n)$ is not infinite. Also, 10. is not correct because you can take $b_n = 0$, for instance.

Comment: I would say "indeterminate" and not undefined.

Comment: @DougM That's a fair criticism. I was only quoting the OP.